# How to add custom information into Zip archive for every ZipArchiveEntry in Java (getComment is always null)

Tags: java, apache, zip, archive

**Using: Java, Apache Commons Compress (1.10)
(`org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream`)
(`org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry`)**

Is there a way, how to add custom information (byte[] or String) for ZIP archive entry?

**I tried to use following methods:**

```
entry.setExtra(byte[] extra);
entry.setExtraFields(ZipExtraField[] fields);
entry.setComment(String comment);
```

But it seems `setExtra` is limited to 2 bytes only and `setExtraFields` takes only ZIP standarized fields, not any custom parameter.

The most promissing `setComment` is always ***null*** (decompression), no matter if and where it is set (compression).

**Compression example (using `setComment`):**

```
ZipArchiveOutputStream zaos = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(fos);
ZipArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchiveEntry(file.getName()); 
entry.setComment("Test");
zaos.putArchiveEntry(entry);
// write data
zaos.closeArchiveEntry();
zaos.finish();
```

On decompression `entry.getComment()` is ***null***.